# could not validate my xml file to be able to use it in DhtmlxGrid

Tags: xml

I am trying to create a data grid using DHTMLXGrid api. A small excerpt from my xml document:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<records>
    <paper>
        <gid>3</gid>
        <tid>1</tid>
        <pid>4</pid>
        <title>Quality Education as I See It</title>
        <authors>Dheeraj Mehrotra</authors>
    </paper>
    <paper>
        <gid>3</gid>
        <tid>1</tid>
        <pid>5</pid>
        <title>e-Learning Concept of CMS and the Digitization of Libraries</title>
        <authors>Meenu Chopra</authors>
```

The problem is that when i run the code, it says incorrect xml, possible reasons for which could be incorrect schema or use of invalid characters. I tried validating this xml file and it gave me this error:

```
     Missing "charset" attribute for "text/xml" document.

The HTTP Content-Type header (text/xml) sent by your web browser (Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.986.0 Safari/535.15) did not contain a "charset" parameter, but the Content-Type was one of the XML text/* sub-types.

The relevant specification (RFC 3023) specifies a strong default of "us-ascii" for such documents so we will use this value regardless of any encoding you may have indicated elsewhere.

If you would like to use a different encoding, you should arrange to have your browser send this new encoding information.


Sorry, I am unable to validate this document because on line 441 it contained one or more bytes that I cannot interpret as us-ascii (in other words, the bytes found are not valid values in the specified Character Encoding). Please check both the content of the file and the character encoding indication.
The error was: ascii "\xE2" does not map to Unicode
```

Line on 441:
Determination of Risk Factor for Marketing A Crop–Using Data Mining

And earlier i corrected some errors like double quotes but it keeps finding more..

The things i want to do with my xml are to validate it, remove the invalid characters somehow and to include unique id to each paper tag coz it is a requirement in DHTMLX API. I created my xml through a csv file which i have originally and it doesnt have any option to create unique id's.

Comment: edited the question to include line 441 data

Answer (score 1):

It's a long `–` symbol. You are using wrong encoding. Make sure you always use UTF-8

Comment: Well thats the problem... i dont know how to create my xml in utf-8 or anything like that. Either tell me how can i prepare it while converting it from csv file or how to convert it to utf-8 later

Comment: 1) Use e.g. the MS Excel. It supports UTF-8 and also you could add the id column which you are asking. Or 2) use the Notepad or any good text editor, then you save it usually offers encoding (by default it's CP1252 or similar). Or 3) use any programming language to write a small utility to convert, most modern languages work with UTF-8.